# Is it mandatory to map PHP SoapFault to WSDL fault element?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapfault

Hello to the community,

I recently implemented a Web Service in native PHP (ie using SoapServer) by using classes in php code and comlex types in WSDL. The Web Service throws 3 type of SoapFaults (exceptions) at any case that something goes "wrong". In all cases, I use faultcode = Receiver to every exception that may come up and custom faultstring to distinct the cases among them.

The question is if it is mandatory to modify my WSDL by adding wsdl:fault elements? Do I have to create separate classes for the fault elements inside my PHP code?

Thanks a lot in advance guys